# Pinch zoom view

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm working on my first app which uses a listactivity that displays names.

When I click one of the listitems it opens a new intent(activity?)that calls an xml layout which contains a textview.

What I want to achieve is getting pinchzoom to work with textviews (or something like it)

Today, finally, I ran across a version to do it with textviews, however I'm not good enough with the language yet to implement the whole class myself.

I have found this tutorial but I can't seem to figure out how to use it: 
http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-6-implementing-the-pinch-zoom-gesture/1847

Could anyone help me out with MyGestureDetector() for this code:

```
private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
private View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;
```

And in onCreate:

```
// Zoom handlers
gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());
gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {

    // We can be in one of these 2 states
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int ZOOM = 1;
    int mode = NONE;

    static final int MIN_FONT_SIZE = 10;
    static final int MAX_FONT_SIZE = 50;

    float oldDist = 1f;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                oldDist = spacing(event);
                Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
                if (oldDist > 10f) {
                   mode = ZOOM;
                   Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM" );
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                mode = NONE;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (mode == ZOOM) {
                    float newDist = spacing(event);
                    // If you want to tweak font scaling, this is the place to go.
                    if (newDist > 10f) {
                        float scale = newDist / oldDist;

                        if (scale > 1) {
                            scale = 1.1f;
                        } else if (scale < 1) {
                            scale = 0.95f;
                        }

                        float currentSize = textView.getTextSize() * scale;
                        if ((currentSize < MAX_FONT_SIZE && currentSize > MIN_FONT_SIZE)
                                ||(currentSize >= MAX_FONT_SIZE && scale < 1)
                                || (currentSize <= MIN_FONT_SIZE && scale > 1)) {
                            textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, currentSize);
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        return false;
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Look into the ScaleGestureDetector ([ScaleGestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ScaleGestureDetector.html)). It handles the pinch nicely, providing you with the scale factor, the focal point, and other things.